# 500 (Internal Server Error) while loading events into a fullcalendar using codeigniter3 and sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, fullcalendar, codeigniter-3

I want to load events into jQuery FullCalendar using Codeigniter3 and SqlServer. I inserted data successfully into Databse table, but while loading data, it raises 500 (Internal Server Error). I changed my ".htaccess" file too, but no use.... Please can anyone give me the solution to overcome this error...
My Error Message is:
http://localhost/patch_cal/index.php/Calendar/get_events?start=1567296000&end=1570924800 500 (Internal Server Error)

.htaccess:

I Method:

Require all denied
   
   
      Deny from all

II Method:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

Calendar Controller:

```
  public function get_events()
 {

   $start = $this->input->get("start");
   $end   = $this->input->get("end");

   $startdt = new DateTime('now'); //Setup a local datetime
   $startdt->setTimestamp($start); //Set the Date based on timestamp
   $start_format = $startdt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   $enddt  = new DateTime('now'); //Setup a local datetime
   $enddt->setTimestamp($end); //Set the Date based on timestamp
   $end_format = $enddt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

   $events = $this->calendar_model->get_events($start_format, 
                   $end_format);

   $data_events = array();

   foreach($events->result() as $r)
   {
   $data_events[] = array(
    "id" => $r->ID,
    "title" => $r->title,
    "description" => $r->description,
    "end" => $r->end_event,
    "start" => $r->start_event
    );
}
echo json_encode($data_events); 
}
```

Calendar_View.php

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

  eventSources: [
       {
         events: function(start, end, timezone, callback){
         $.ajax({
            url:'<?php echo site_url("Calendar/get_events"); ?>',
            dataType:'json',
            data:{
                start: start.unix(),
                end: end.unix()
                },
            success: function(msg){
            var events = msg.events;
            callback(events); 
        } 
          });
            }
            },
    ],
```

I want to load data into FullCalendar default view....

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located that you are changing? From your comments it' sounds like you are playing with internal .htaccess files which you should not be touching. Only the one in your public folder.

Comment: My initial file was like this...<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>

Comment: By googling I changed to above code... But no use.. Same Error...    Can you suggest me do I need any changes...

Comment: If that is what is in the htaccess file you are changing, you are changing the wrong one. You need to change the one in your public_html or whatever is your public root folder. Read the codeigniter guide on it.

Comment: Internal server error could mean anything, it just means the server code crashed. Not sure why we are assuming it's related to htaccess necessarily. Did the error only start after you changed the htaccess? It would probably make more sense to look in the PHP error log and see if there are any useful exception details there (assuming your server has PHP error logging switched on).

Comment: Do you have `$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;` in your main config file? If yes than you either need to add the url to the `$config['csrf_exclude_uris']` or send the token name and hash with your ajax data something like this: `data: {'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'`